# dompdf inside docker container: file_put_contents(x/x) failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: docker, dompdf

I'm running a php app inside docker container and when printing a document I get this error:

> file_put_contents(/var/www/html/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/lib/fonts/fonts\aefcc7f4826ca47c6196f471bf48339a.ufm.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory

After checking I found that the path is indeed wrong and the right path is:

```
/var/www/html/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/lib/fonts/aefcc7f4826ca47c6196f471bf48339a.ufm.php
```

and not sure why it adds the extra `/fonts` !!
when I was running this app on wamp it was working fine, why it's not the case inside a docker container ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I found the solution and I'm gonna leave it here in case someone may face this issue.
the problem is in the `/lib/dompdf_font_family_cache.php` where we need to change `backslash \ to forward slash /` and this was fixed in the latest version of dompdf (I'm using **0.8.2** and the last version is **0.8.5**)
so all we need to do is ti upgrade to the latest version `composer require dompdf/dompdf:^0.8.5`